# laravel facebook no redirect back if app allowed already

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-php-sdk

I made the auth with socialite/facebook.

My code --

config/services.php:

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => 'client_id',
    'client_secret' => 'client_secret',
    'redirect' => 'http://www.example.com/facebook/callback',
],
```

routes.php:

```
Route::get('facebook', 'FacebookController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('facebook/callback', 'FacebookController@handleProviderCallback');
```

FacebookController.php:

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::with('facebook')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $users = Socialite::with('facebook')->user();

    // user registration and login
    // if the user is in the database, just login

    return redirect()->back();   
}
```

Everything works fine, the registration, the login and the redirect until one point.

If the app is already allowed, it redirects back normally. If you first authenticate with Facebook and allow the app, it does not redirect.

However, if the redirect is the homepage:

```
 return redirect('/');
```

then it works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i found the solution here:
http://laravel.io/forum/08-03-2014-redirect-to-the-second-last-page

My solved code:

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    // added this
    Session::flash('url',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    return Socialite::with('facebook')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $users = Socialite::with('facebook')->user();

    // user registration and login
    // if the user is in the database, just login

    // redirect changed from redirect()->back(); to this
    return Redirect::to(Session::get('url'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Choose Your App in `https://developers.facebook.com` and go through the `App Review` option  available in the dashboard and make your app public and full fill the Approval criteria

My main point is that you have everything ok in your side just make some small changes on developer dashboard in the facebook app.

Comment: I checked the App Review section, but it's public, and in the Facebook login settings, the callback is correct - http://www.example.com/facebook/callback